# Why LiveData is slow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

In my application, I load data from the local database and it's very slow. I tried to find what is slow and I found that this occurs because of LiveData.

I created a sample application to test LiveData speed here you are my test code:
FirstFragment:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), FirstFragmentCallback {
private val TAG = FirstFragment::class.java.simpleName

private var mViewModel: FirstFragmentViewModel? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mViewModel = ActivityUtils.obtainViewModel(requireActivity(), FirstFragmentViewModel::class.java)
    (mViewModel as FirstFragmentViewModel).callback = this
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView called")

    registerObservables()
    mViewModel?.loadData()
    return v
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val secondFragmentButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.second)
    secondFragmentButton.setOnClickListener {
        ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentInActivity(requireFragmentManager(), SecondFragment(), R.id.container, false)
    }
}

private fun registerObservables(){
    mViewModel?.dataLoadedEvent?.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG, "dataLoaded event")
    })
    mViewModel?.dataLoaded2Event?.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG, "dataLoaded2 event")
    })
}

override fun dataLoaded() {
    Log.d(TAG, "dataLoaded callback")
}
}
```

FirstFragmentViewModel:

```
class FirstFragmentViewModel(val mAppliction: Application): AndroidViewModel(mAppliction) {

val dataLoadedEvent: SingleLiveEvent<Void> = SingleLiveEvent()

val dataLoaded2Event: MutableLiveData<Void> = MutableLiveData()

var callback: FirstFragmentCallback? = null

fun loadData(){
    dataLoadedEvent.postValue(null)
    dataLoaded2Event.postValue(null)
    callback?.dataLoaded()
}
}
```

If I run this fragment I got these in the LogCat:

> 2019-05-15 13:23:07.405 8632-8632/livedatatest D/FirstFragment: onCreateView called
>
> 2019-05-15 13:23:07.406 8632-8632/livedatatest D/FirstFragment: dataLoaded callback
>
> 2019-05-15 13:23:07.438 8632-8632/livedatatest D/FirstFragment: dataLoaded event
>
> 2019-05-15 13:23:07.439 8632-8632/livedatatest D/FirstFragment: dataLoaded2 event

You can see that `dataLoadedEvent.postValue(null)` take at least 30ms, but the simple callback is called immediately.

Is there any solution to speed up LiveData events?

Comment: 30ms is slow for you?!

Comment: A delay of 30ms is almost impossible to notice. The reason why your app is slow must certainly be somewhere else.

Comment: If I using it in a bigger project the delay is bigger ~300ms.

Comment: If the `LiveData` instance is having so much trouble reaching the main thread to deliver the value, then the app is probably doing too much work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You can see that dataLoadedEvent.postValue(null) take at least 30ms

`postValue()` is for when you want to update the `MutableLiveData` from a background thread. Under the covers, it uses a `Handler` to route your event to the main application thread. Therefore, there will be some delay, as other main application thread work queue events get processed.

It also illustrates that your benchmark is flawed ("comparing apples to oranges"). Either:

- Use `Handler` instead of a callback (or some other "run this code on the main application thread" approach), or
- Use `setValue()` (or `value=` since you are in Kotlin) instead of `postValue()`, to update the `MutableLiveData` content directly on the main application thread

Comment: Thanks! I changed the `postValue()` to `.value = ` and it's more faster.